# Copy Mac com.apple.ResourceFork extended attribute causing "Argument list too long"

Tags: macos, shell, command-line, xattr, file-forks

I'm trying to copy extended attributes from one file to another using the OSX "xattr" utility.  The background is that we are building a backup tool and the files/structure must retain all attributes, ACLs, etc... Everything is working fine except large attributes like resource forks.  Small attributes work fine using method below.  Attempting this on OS X 10.7.5 Here is what I am doing:

First I identify the attributes on a file using "ls -l@".  Result below:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 testuser  staff        0  3 Jan  2011 File
        com.apple.FinderInfo         32 
        com.apple.ResourceFork   237246
```

Now I export the attribute (com.apple.ResourceFork is the one causing issues):

```
xattr -px com.apple.ResourceFork File > attribfile
```

I now want to apply this attribute to the copy of the file on another mac using this command:

```
xattr -wx com.apple.ResourceFork "`cat attribfile`" File
```

This results in:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/xattr: Argument list too long
```

I think I know why it is happening... the resource fork data is way too long to fit in an argument.  I have not established the threshold at which it starts to break but I suspect it has to do with ARG_MAX.  xargs doesn't help here since it is not several smaller arguments, but one very large one.

So multiple questions:

1. Is there a way to make xattr accept this large value?  Somehow pipe it in via standard input? man page does not show it, but I am not an expert and maybe there is some creative way to do it
2. Can anyone tell me the proper way to apply a large extended attribute using stock command line tools?
3. if there is no stock command line tools, any recommendations for 3rd party tools?

Comment: This could be getting a little involved, but it might not be impossible to reverse-engineer `xattr` and write your own simple replacement which accepts a file of attributes as its input. If you're lucky, there's a single system call with a binding in a convenient scripting language - Perl one-liner?

Comment: We're looking at this option.  Looks like the tool is MIT license, so its commercial friendly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it with `xattr`, but there's an old filesystem trick you can use. Note: this is basically obsolete, but still works in 10.8.2; I make no promises about 10.8.3 etc.  If the attribfile is in hex format, use this:

```
xxd -r -p attribfile >File/..namedfork/rsrc
```

If the attribfile is raw, use `cat` instead of `xxd -r -p`. If the attribute is something other than the resource fork, ... I have no idea.

Comment: hmmm, I tried exporting the resource forks that way and it was failing in 10.7+.  Never tried setting it in that way.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: Well it seems this does work, which solves the problem of resource forks!  Thanks!

Comment: You could also do without the intermediate temporary file:
`xattr -p -x com.apple.ResourceFork src | xxd -p -r - > dst/..namedfork/rsrc`

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer did not work for me, so I continued and found another solution, which I post here in case other people need it.

My problem was copying vlc-2.1.4 to the /Applications folder. It kept saying:

```
The Finder can’t complete the operation because some data in “VLC” can’t be read or written.
(Error code -36)
```

And If I tried using a `cp` in the terminal i was getting the error indicated in this thread.

So what I did was to execute the following commands in the console (summarizing I `tar` the VLC and untar it in its destination, so ... it works as a `cp`):

```
cd /Volumes/vlc-2.1.4/
tar cf /Applications/vlc.tar  VLC.app
cd /Applications/
tar xf vlc.tar 
rm vlc.tar
```

I hope this will be useful for others with the same problem.